В поле какого типа передавать на фронтенд расшифровку статуса: строка или enum?
Есть api которое возвращает на фронтэнд модель с полем status.
enum Status {
    ERROR,
    SUCCESS
}

Требуется отобразить пользователю причину ошибки или детали успешного завершения на русском языке.
1. Стоит ли передавать это сообщение как есть с бэканда в строковом поле?
Структура:
{
    id: int
    status: Status
    statusDescription: string
}

Пример:
{
    id: 210,
    status: "ERROR",
    statusDescription: "Товар не найден"
}

2. Или же правильнее передать enum, а на фронтенде уже будет сформировать сообщение?
Структура:
{
    id: int
    status: Status
    statusDescription: StatusDescription
}

enum statusDescription{
    PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND,
    CUSTOMER_NOT_FOUND
}

Пример:
{
    id: 210,
    status: "ERROR",
    statusDescription: "PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND"
}


Да разницы нет, если только не делать многоязычный фронтэнд. В многоязычный фронтэнд лучше передавать коды, а он уже будет преобразовывать в строку на нужном языке.
